# Accessing files affect IO performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, file, ubuntu, filesystems

We are using the approach to managing the assets of the application based on the dynamic files and folders on the Ubuntu System.

Like for example a product have many images, So the approach which we are following right now is

```
- product-name(folder)
  - image-id(folder)
    - image(file)
  - image-id(folder)
    - image(file)
  - image-id(folder)
    - image(file)
```

And the approach we are thinking like...

```
- product-name(folder)
  - image1(file)
  - image1(file)
  - image1(file)
```

Will both the approaches make any IO performance diff on the operating system or both will be able to access the file in same time frame?

Please help.

Comment: The effect is of using subfolders is probably extremely marginal. I would instead focus on measures that actually matter like using a reverse proxy (such as Squid, Varnish or Rack::Cache) or a CDN to serve static files.